# XML Value count not work

Tags: php, xml

i have a example.xml file and its implement in php for getting value like from this code

```
<?php 
$xml=simplexml_load_file(example.xml);
$xmlbid=$xml->RESULTS->LISTING->value; 
?>
```

this code working fine like when i enter echo `$xmlbid` it return me `0.002` value
this is value in xml file its fine.
but problem is when i multiply some value with $xmlbid and its save to another variable and then echo this variable its return me 0 why
like this

```
$mul=$xmlbid*0.7;
```

its return 0 why please help me solve this

Answer (score 1, accepted):

are you sure it's in the correct format, using the right decimal separator?

you can try this:

```
<?php 
$locale = localeconv();

$xml=simplexml_load_file(example.xml);
$xmlbid=$xml->RESULTS->LISTING->value; 

$xmlbid = (float)str_replace(',', '.', str_replace($locale['decimal_point'], '.', $xmlbid));
$mul=$xmlbid*0.7;

?>
```

it will replace the decimal separator to a point and also the comma, just to make sure :) actually one of these is enough probably, it depends on the input.

Comment: could you please mark my answer right then? i'm new to stackoverflow and try to get some reputation points if possible